# running PHP script from cpanel cron scheduler

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have been looking all over the place and every line I try does not work.

the latest line:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/testing/filename/process/process_01.php
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in
>   /home/username/public_html/testing/filename/lib/dbconfig.php on line
>   10

I can run this script from the browser no problem and I am 99% sure the path to PHP is correct in the line.

I only have access to cpanel cron job manager no command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is a problem related to the include directory.

Try going to the folder first and running from there:

```
cd /home/username/public_html/testing/filename/process/; /usr/local/bin/php process_01.php
```

Depending on how the include is done, you may need to "cd" into a previous folder in the hierarchy.